# Modrewrite allow numbers, letters, underscore

Tags: mod-rewrite

I want to have a url that will allow for a tag to have underscores, numbers, and letters of any combination (uppercase or lowercase).

Example: `tags/WhaTever_eyE_D3sire`

```
RewriteRule ^tags/([A-Za-z0-9]+)$ tags/$1/ [R,QSA]
RewriteRule ^tags/([A-Za-z0-9]+)/$ index.php?state=tags&tag=$1 [L,QSA]
```

That is what I have right now.  Can someone please tell me the proper syntax I need to make this happen?  Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All you need to add in is the underscore, which should be something like this I believe.

```
RewriteRule ^tags/([A-Za-z0-9_]+)$ tags/$1/ [R,QSA]
RewriteRule ^tags/([A-Za-z0-9_]+)/$ index.php?state=tags&tag=$1 [L,QSA]
```

But then again, you never really describe the problem you were having.